# Is there a way to do productsum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula like =and(or(isblank(x),x="")

where x can be A1,A4,A7,A9,... all of these.

I though of sumproduct but that is if the formula were or(and(isblank(x), x=""))

Of course the solution would be to build the formula
=and(or(isblank(x),x=""),or(isblank(y),y=""),...)

Comment: You need a formula to check if ALL of the cells you specify are blank?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3)=""
```